# Will iCloud sync interfere with Gmail Contacts/Calendars sync?

Tags: data-synchronization, gmail, contacts, calendar, icloud

I'm looking to setup with iCloud, and I'm concerned with their desire to sync my contacts, calendars, and bookmarks.  While I'm fine with the bookmarks, I am legitimately concerned about contacts and calendars since I consider that the domain of Gmail Contacts and Google Calendar, which I've had synced via Gmail Sync for some time now.

Will iCloud sync interfere with Gmail sync?  Or does iCloud simply offer me another layer of redundancy?

Answer (score 3):

With iCloud, you can choose which areas to sync and which not to.  However, if you do choose to sync contacts and/or calendar, I believe you will simply end up with some double events on your phone, which can easily be cleared up by disabling view of the extra calendars.

In short, syncing contacts, calendar, music, and photos are all separate and can be enabled/disabled as such.

And yes, it does, in some way offer you additional redundancy as the Apple cloud and Google cloud are likely housed in different data centers...but this would require you to keep both calendars in sync, which I don't think will be easy to do without being annoyed absurdly.

Comment: It would duplicate events?  After having given it more thought, I would figure they would simply replicate off of each other.  I wouldn't enable the seperate calendar on my iPhone or iPad, I would be just having iCloud sync events through my iMac.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe you end up with duplicate calendars, but in my case, I sync with Exchange so that makes it a whole 'nother kitten.
Basically, on your iphone, I think its going to find both your icloud calendar and your google calendar, and each will get its own color and you're left to cleanup the mess.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, iCloud seems to interfere with google contact syncing.  When you try to enable iCloud contact syncing on 10.7.2, you will see a dialog that will force you to disable Google Contact syncing. See [How can I use iCloud to sync my contacts, while also syncing my contacts with Google?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27603/how-can-i-use-icloud-to-sync-my-contacts-while-also-syncing-my-contacts-with-goo)

Comment: It seems that you really can't use both on any level, or it just causes problems.  Within Lion it prevents it, and on your phone/ipad it will cause odd duplication.  You can't have one way syncing where it will just push updates to iCloud while using read/write for Google.  Sticking with Google for now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, best to stick to one sync. Just had the fun of having to delete lots of merged information. Trust me  you dpn't want to go there