# How can I use iCloud to sync my contacts, while also syncing my contacts with Google?

Tags: gmail, icloud, google-sync, macos

If you have Google contact syncing enabled in 10.7.1 or earlier, then upgrade to 10.7.2 and try to enable iCloud contact syncing, you will see the following dialog:

[image: Google sync will be turned off if you use iCloud for your contacts]

Is it possible to have both worlds?  I would like to sync with iCloud for my iOS/mac devices, but ALSO sync with google for my gmail/android devices.  This used to be possible with mobileme.

Comment: Excellent question. Anyone?

Comment: How is this still so poorly thought out in late 2011?

Answer (score 6):

Doesn't look like this is presently possible.  Only way to get this to work is use Google Contacts as the main source, and then set [OS X Address book to sync to Google](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=AddressBook/5.0/en/21507.html), and use [Google ActiveSync](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2480) on the iPhone to also sync contacts with Google.

Answer (score 6):

Well... I also want to use contacts from GMail. So... After reading that there was no solution, I came to a very simple solution: Don't use iCloud for contacts. Period.

Each Apple device can be setup to sync with GMail contacts - and that's it.

Works for me.

Comment: Works for me too. With the added bonus of working just as well on many non-Apple devices, should you ever need to. (I do.)

Answer (score 5):

As for Contacts, the best solution, as of March 2012, is to:

- Google Contacts as the main source, you get backups for free without doing anything
- On OS X, configure the Address Book to sync to Google
- On iOS, [configure Gmail as Exchange](http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740), not as Gmail (counter intuitive but that's the way!)

Keep iClould out of your contacts for some time, until Apple will include native support for Gmail contacts, which I doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring iCloud and using Google's ActiveSync is not a solution which works for everyone. ActiveSync is limited in number of data entries in your address book which can be synced, and the name of these data entries. In short:

- 3 email addresses
- 2 home numbers
- 1 home fax number
- 1 mobile number
- 1 pager number
- 3 work number (one will be labeled 'Company Main')
- 1 work fax number.

Numbers have to be named exactly as stated above. Other names like "Support" or "Hotline" won't be synced without displaying any errors.

See [Google Sync Known Issues with iOS](http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139635) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, doesn't seem possible.[This website](http://iphonehelp.in/2011/10/14/icloud-doesnt-work-with-google-sync/) categorically says so.