# Using OS X Server resources on non-Macs

Tags: contacts, osx-server, ical, sharing, open-directory

I currently have two Mac Mini servers with several Mac clients and everything works well (DNS, Open Directory, Contacts/Calendar/Messaging, File Sharing, Time Machine, etc). I'm open to introducing Windows 7/10 and Linux (Ubuntu/CentOS) into the environment as BYOD option. Mail is handled by two linux mail servers (IMAP only).

Does OS X server integrate into these environments? I'm sure both can join Open Directory, or at least Linux can.

Most importantly, how can I get Contacts/Cal to work across Android/Windows mobile and desktop devices?

OS X 10.10 Server

Comment: For Contacts and Calendar, you have iCould.com. In my point of view, a great way to have iCloud Contact/Calendar on Android/PC platform is to synchronise iCloud and Google http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75360/how-to-sync-icloud-contacts-with-google

Comment: The server already hosts iCal/Contacts and Messenger. Using iCloud.com doesn't tie into my local system like Outlook365 does with a local AD server. At least not that I'm aware of. Is it possible to have the local network share out to iCloud.com for the users who don't run Macs? I need a user who isn't at the office to get invitations to meetings/appointments without having to first sync the event on their computer.

Comment: It isn't really an answer to your question, but if it will put you at ease: brew and MacPorts are free, open source methods of porting much of the software available for Linux and FreeBSD to Mac OS. In general, it's a safe bet that if you can do it in Linux, you can do it in OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Server data app on OS X is highly standards compliant. LDAP is industry-standard (but it's not active directory),  Mail is IMAP, CardDAV, WebDAV and CalDAV. All are quite standard and ubiquitous.  Filesharing uses SMB3.

Unless you have highly specific/rigid client requirements or are wedded to certain client apps, you should be able to make productive use of server.app services across multiple client operating systems.

Comment: I'm aware of the standards but I wasn't sure if Apple modifies something to make it more proprietary or not. And I wasn't sure on the compatibility of other OSes. At this point I'm small enough that I can get by with Profile Manager and FileVault2 to secure the client systems. My concern is having data synced to mobile devices.

Comment: @Markaway Cool - since it's free to ask follow on questions - feel free to ask a more specific question. Integration is in the details - sometimes a minor version bump can change things. I figured a general answer to a broad question would be of use. :-)

Comment: I believe I had asked about it in my original question. How to handle other devices.

Comment: @Markaway Cool - it's far too broad a subject for me to be more specific - I'm not comfortable making guesses as to what "other devices" means in your situation. Let's see if someone else has better insight than I or can offer sage advice/pointers..

Comment: What 'other devices' - I have Windows/Android specified for both mobile and desktop. My question is how to get iCal/Contacts to work across mixed environments like Windows and Android devices. I can see how that can be broad but I'm not expecting a step-by-step answer either. If there's an application to use i'm not aware of that would be acceptable.