# Synchronize only selected Google contacts on iphone

Tags: iphone, contacts, gmail

Following [these](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75360/how-to-sync-icloud-contacts-with-google) instructions, I was able to synchronize all my Google contacts to iOS.

However, this bundled together *all* my Google contacts: people without phone numbers, people I haven't communicated with in years, etc... I was hoping to see only my frequent contacts list.

Is it possible to only synchronize a selected group of contacts on the iphone? Alternatively, can I only *show* a few of the groups, as is possible with iCloud contact groups?