# Is it possible to sync the same contact to multiple accounts in iOS?

Tags: data-synchronization, gmail, ios, contacts, icloud

In iOS, when one goes to Settings -> Contacts -> Default account, one can choose the cloud account (for example iCloud, Gmail etc.), to sync a newly created contact by default. Is there a way to sync the same contact to multiple accounts. Flow:

1. Create a contact on iPhone.
2. Go to gmail.com -> Contacts and the contact should be there.
3. Go to icloud.com -> Contact and the contact should be there.

Basically, I want to have the same set of contacts in both accounts without, of course, having duplicates on my phone.

Comment: [Is it possible to sync the same contact to multiple accounts in iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75360/how-to-sync-icloud-contacts-with-google?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Not a straightforward way, but I export all contacts in Contacts.app in a format that Google Contacts receives. Then upload them all there and clean up all the duplicates.

Then export a file from Google Contacts. Delete all iCloud contacts and then import the file I just got.

But ever since I started using photos for people's phone numbers, this doesn't work.