# How to sync contacts between iCloud and Gmail with Mavericks

Tags: icloud, macos, gmail

The question is not about enabling the new two-way gmail syncing on Mavericks, or how to activate the iCloud one. What I'm trying to do is just to sync the two.

Manually I could from time to time erase all the gmail contacts and copy all the contacts I have on iCloud. But is there an automated way to do it ?

Comment: The app [Cobook Contacts](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/cobook-contacts/id525225808?l=en&mt=12) for Mac **used** to do this with mixed results, but recently (since Mavericks) seems to be broken. Very interested in a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Another point concerns the `linked` cards: it is possible to manually or automatically link identical cards from different sources. A modification will then propagate to the other accounts. However this doesn't solve the problem when creating a new card. Additionally the automatic linking doesn't work identically on Mavericks and iOS7.

Comment: If the linked question doesn't solve your problem, feel free to edit in exactly why the answers there do not work - perhaps listing an error or missing UI interface if needed to clarify why this isn't a duplicate. We can reopen if this isn't already covered adequately.

Comment: Also - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27603/how-can-i-use-icloud-to-sync-my-contacts-while-also-syncing-my-contacts-with-go?rq=1