# Sync Google contacts and iCloud contacts

Tags: iphone, ios, google-sync

I use CardDav to get my Google Contacts on my iPhone, which works great, but I would love it when those contacts were also in sync with iCloud contacts.

Meaning when I add John Doe in Google contacts it will show up in iCloud (eventually) and vice versa when I add Jane Doe in iCloud it will show up in Google contacts.

I've got an iPhone 4S with iOS7 and a MBP with Mavericks.

Comment: I'm linking this to [that](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107225/how-to-sync-contacts-between-icloud-and-gmail-with-mavericks) question if this threads gets an proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just saw a question similar to yours, Apple does not allow sync of contacts between various cloud accounts (i.e. between Google and iCloud), however you can use this tutorial to [transfer or copy contacts from one iPhone cloud account (Google) to the next (iCloud)](http://www.copytrans.net/support/how-to-transfer-iphone-contacts-between-cloud-accounts/).

Comment: Do you have a reference for "Apple does not allow sync of contacts between various cloud accounts"? Thanks

Comment: Example: try to merge Gmail contacts with Yahoo contacts on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just copied my iCloud contacts to Gmail (copied, not synced) just by following those easy steps (I believe Maverick is required but not sure though):
- Add both your iCloud and Gmail account to Mavericks' account manager (in the System prefs) 
- Open the Contacts app on your mac (You should see two different contact folder on the left: iCloud and Google)
- Click the iCloud one, select all of your contacts (cmd+A, shift+click, whatever)
- Drag'n'Drop them from iCloud to Google.
- Voilà !

(It took me more than 5 minutes to converts my 350+ contacts)

Comment: I'm sure this works except this is not a answer to my question. I want to keep them synchronized that means no converting, copying, dragging and what not..